# Iphone Simulator - simulate roaming

Tags: iphone, simulator, roaming

Is it possible to simulate roaming case in iPhone Simulator?

Comment: I don't think that functionality exists.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible variant I know about is described here [accelerometer simulator](http://iphonesdktutorials.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/iphone-accelerometer-simulator/)